# How to fix angular-strap css

Tags: css, angular-strap

I have added the css from the github comments but there is still something wrong. everything in the calendar is not sized correctly.

```
.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 }
 .datepicker.dropdown-menu button {
 outline: none;
 border: 0px;
}
 .datepicker.dropdown-menu tbody {
 height: 180px;
  }
.datepicker.dropdown-menu tbody button {
padding: 6px;
}
 .datepicker.dropdown-menu.datepicker-mode-1 tbody button, .datepicker.dropdown-menu.datepicker-   mode-2 tbody button {
height: 65px;
}

 .timepicker.dropdown-menu {
 padding: 0 4px;
}
.timepicker.dropdown-menu button {
outline: none;
border: 0px;
}
.timepicker.dropdown-menu tbody button {
padding: 6px;
```

[image: pic]  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure to include **this** css **LAST** so it does not get overwriten by another file or other css you typed

Comment: i just put it at the top of the modal header to make sure nothing was over riding it. nothing. same